# mounting harddrive on ubuntu gives error?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, windows, 22.04

I am trying to perform a simple task (to the native ubuntu user, but not to me :D): mounting an external harddrive on my rasperry pi, in order to copy some data onto it, then connecting it back to my windows pc and transfer the data.

I identified the harddrive by `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.48 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors
Disk model: Elements 25A2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
```

I followed some steps that I found online:

- `mkdir mnt_sda`
- `sudo mount /dev/sda mnt_sda/`

The latter gives me the following error:

```
mount: /home/user/mnt_sda: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I also read something about having to create a new linux-compatible partition on the drive first, but it seems the disk needs to be completely reformatted for this and the existing data will be lost. Any way to circumvent this?

Thanks!

Comment: `sda` is a device; isn't there a partition on the device?  ie. `sda1` for example.... Normally you mount partitions, not drives themselves (*there are exceptions for some really old non-standard pre-windows OSes; common in 1980s for example, less so come the 1990s etc*)

Comment: so, would it be possible to create a separate unallocated partition to be recognized by linux? i don't know how to see the partitions..

Comment: `sda` is **not** a partition, it's a device, or in this case a *block* device that is likely a hard drive, ssd, or other type of *block* device.  A drive/device can be split into *partitions* which are called `sda1` etc... but they are just entries in the partition table really.  You allocate space when you create the partition, un-allocated space is just un-allocated space & cannot be by its nature a *partition* & have space assigned to it.  Un-allocated space gets assigned to partitions at which point it's *allocated*.  Possibly you mean *allocated* space that hasn't been given a file-system

Comment: yes, what i mean is using free space on the disk (which is part of some existing partition) and splitting it into a separate partition that is compatible with both linux and windows. alternatively, just use a single partition that is compatible with both. when plugging the drive to windows, i see it is ntfs formatted...

Comment: ok, i figured it out: i had to use the -t ntfs option with mount; additionally, as you pointed out, i had to indicate the partition not the device. so, to summarize: 
```sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 mnt_sda/``` did the job. thank you

Comment: Please write your last comment as an answer; you can then answer your own question & gain some rep. (*when or if you accept it as the best answer*).  fyi:  Well done for solving it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i figured it out: i had to use the -t ntfs option with mount; additionally, as guiverc pointed out, i had to indicate the partition (sda1) not the device (sda). so, to summarize: `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 mnt_sda/` did the job.